# Error loading a image file into ndarray with scipy.ndimage.imread

Tags: python, scipy

Im trying to load a image file into a ndarray with something like this:

```
image_data = ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float)
```

but i get this error:

```
/home/milos/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/io.py in imread(fname, flatten, mode)
     23     if _have_pil:
     24         return _imread(fname, flatten, mode)
---> 25     raise ImportError("Could not import the Python Imaging Library (PIL)"
     26                       " required to load image files.  Please refer to"
     27                       " http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL/ for installation"

ImportError: Could not import the Python Imaging Library (PIL) required   to load image files.  Please refer to http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL/ for   installation instructions.
```

I have Pillow installed inside the environment from which im running the notebook, it also shows up on pip freeze.
I also tried running it from the console but got similar error.

Any ideas how to fix this? Or is there a alternative way to load a image into ndarray?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to do it in the end by bypassing scipy :

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(image_file)
image_data = np.array(img).astype(float)
```

would still like to know what the problem is with scipy, so please post if you know it

Edit :

Found a better solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image_data = mpimg.imread(image_file)
```

this creates a numpy ndarray and normalizes the pixel depths to 0-1, and it worked nicely if i wanted to do a backwards conversion to check if its still good:

```
plt.imshow(image_data)
```

Comment: Thanks, I could just fix Udacity´s Deep Learning Course Assignment 1, which relies on scipy and it did not run using Python3. I used your solution above to directly replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python 2.7.x and encountering the same problem. I'm not sure what's going on with scipy.ndimage.imread() in this context either. Uninstalling Pillow (PIL) does not resolve the problem. So, I did the same as what Milos proposed and it worked:

```
import PIL
import numpy as np
image_file = './my_image.png'
image_data = np.array(PIL.Image.open(image_file)).astype(float)
```